# Why is "sudo expo start" giving "unable to resolve root"?

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo

I'm trying to run a react native app in expo, and after creating a blank app with expo init, when I cd into my project and do expo start, I get the following error:

```
events.js:282
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unable to resolve root /Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name: failed to opendir(/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name): Operation not permitted
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
    at /Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:130:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:107:12)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at /Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name/node_modules/bser/index.js:249:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  watchmanResponse: {
    version: '4.7.0',
    error: 'unable to resolve root /Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name: failed to opendir(/Users/myusername/Documents/native-app-name): Operation not permitted'
  }
}
```

Why might this be?

Comment: were you able to solve it by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your project folder to a different place on your local. I just tried and worked for me.